# Parse JSON string to a JSON Object in C# without writing extra object classes

Tags: c#, wpf, json, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to C# and I am building a WPF app. Right now I trying to figure out how I can parse a JSON string like this:

```
{
   "Name": "Apple", 
   "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00","Price": 3.99, 
   "Sizes": ["Small","Medium","Large"]
}
```

into a JSON Object magically.

I did some search online and all the solutions requires writing an object class that has the same structure as the JSON string. The string above is just an example and the actually JSON response is much more complicated, so I don't want to write a huge class for it.

Is there a library that allows me to do something similar to these:

```
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject(JsonString);
string name = jo["Name"]; // And the name would have "Apple" as its value
```

Comment: Have a look at Newtonsoft.Json http://james.newtonking.com/json

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd recommend you use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) as your JSON library. The following code creates a `dynamic` object that you can work with. `magic` is actually an instance of [`JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) in your example, by the way.

```
dynamic magic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);
string name1 = magic.Name;    // "Apple"
string name2 = magic["Name"]; // "Apple"
```

Comment: You could also map your result object to a class:
  var resultObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CLASSHERE>(OBJECT.ToString());

Comment: nice, I agree `dynamic` object is probably the most simple way to do this.

Comment: @Tim S. Fantastic! This is just the magic I want! Thank you so much!