# Json.NET not parsing string to json object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert a json string to a .net object, i am using the next code which i got from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788850/parse-json-string-to-a-json-object-in-c-sharp-without-writing-extra-object-class):

```
dynamic answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
Console.WriteLine(answer.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(answer["db"]);
```

The json string is this one:

> ```
> [
>    {
>       "db":"6-y4XlvtqzR.sqlite",
>       "users":"INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, password, email, cel, level) VALUES (17,a,b,f7a9e,e@gmail.com,2,3),(29,c,d,7c4a8d,f@hotmail.com,1,4)"
>    }
> ]
> ```

The problem is that the application crashes on the third line of my c# code above, and the message error is the next:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

What is the probem with my code? is my json string wrong? or how can i get the json object right?

The funny thing about this is that the second line of the c# code is executed fine and it prints the right string.

Comment: `answer` is an array

Comment: You are right, i set Console.WriteLine(answer[0]["db"]); and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it with a type specified, such as (assuming `ObjectType` is the desired return type):

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectType>(responseString);
```

And why did you use `dynamic`?

Answer (score 0):

Your responsestring  should be formatted properly like this,

> "{\"db\":\"6-y4XlvtqzR.sqlite\",\"users\":\"INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, password, email, cel, level) VALUES (17,a,b,f7a9e,e@gmail.com,2,3),(29,c,d,7c4a8d,f@hotmail.com,1,4)\"}"

I created following sample and monitored the Json result for the object. Hope this will help.

```
class Program
{

    class TestClass
    {
        public string db { get; set; }
        public string users { get; set; }

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass ts = new TestClass();
        ts.db = "6-y4XlvtqzR.sqlite";
        ts.users =
            "INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, password, email, cel, level) VALUES (17,a,b,f7a9e,e@gmail.com,2,3),(29,c,d,7c4a8d,f@hotmail.com,1,4)";

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ts);
        dynamic answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        Console.WriteLine(answer.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(answer["db"]);

    }
}
```