# Binding JSON object inside of array in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, marklogic

I have a JSON response from MarkLogic that I am binding to a model in C#. The relevant snippet is below:

```
{  
   "snippets":{  
      "match":[  
         {  
            "value":[  
               "In (consolidated) enforcement actions for failure to answer subpoena, appeal from ",
               {  
                  "highlight":{  
                     "value":"judgement"
                  }
               },
               " for defendants."
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The problem I am having is with the outer "value" array, since it contains two strings and another JSON object. Is there any way I can bind this array in C#? My current models look like this:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "snippets")]
public MarkLogicSnippetsModel Snippets { get; set; }

public class MarkLogicSnippetsModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "match")]
    public IEnumerable<MarkLogicMatchModel> Matches { get; set; }
}

public class MarkLogicMatchModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

But using `IEnumerable<string>` doesn't work when there is an object in the array.

Comment: The JSON is not valid.

Comment: @PaulSwetz I fixed it, this is only a part of the response that is returned, which is why it wasn't valid when I copied it

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though the JSON is supposed to represent matches in some overall string, in this case a match of the string "judgement" in [*In (consolidated) enforcement actions for failure to answer subpoena, appeal from judgement for defendants.*](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22In+%28consolidated%29+enforcement+actions+for+failure+to+answer+subpoena%2C+appeal+from%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)  Thus, your data model is going to need to be able to reconstruct the entire string, as well as pick out the matched portion.

Assuming the JSON cannot be changed, I'd suggest a data model like the following:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "snippets")]
    public MarkLogicSnippetsModel Snippets { get; set; }
}

public class MarkLogicSnippetsModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "match")]
    public IEnumerable<MarkLogicMatchModel> Matches { get; set; }
}

public class MarkLogicMatchModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public List<MarkLogicMatchEntry> Values { get; set; }
}

public enum MatchType
{
    Normal,
    Highlight,
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MarkLogicMatchEntryConverter))]
public class MarkLogicMatchEntry
{
    public MatchType MatchType { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following converter:

```
class MarkLogicMatchEntryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    JsonSerializer GetEnumSerializer()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true } } });
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MarkLogicMatchEntry);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            return new MarkLogicMatchEntry { MatchType = MatchType.Normal, Value = reader.Value.ToString() };
        }
        else
        {
            var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            var property = obj.Properties().FirstOrDefault();
            var type = ((JValue)property.Name).ToObject<MatchType>(GetEnumSerializer());
            var value = (string)property.Value.SelectToken("value");

            return new MarkLogicMatchEntry { MatchType = type, Value = value };
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var match = (MarkLogicMatchEntry)value;
        if (match.MatchType == MatchType.Normal)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(match.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            var propertyName = (string)JToken.FromObject(match.MatchType, GetEnumSerializer());
            var obj = new JObject(new JProperty(propertyName, new JObject(new JProperty("value", match.Value))));
            obj.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Here each section of the searched string is represented by a `MarkLogicMatchEntry` class.  Normal, unmatched substrings are represented with `MatchType = MatchType.Normal`.  Matched substrings are represented with `MatchType = MatchType.Highlight`.  In theory other match types such as `MatchType.Underline` could be added if required.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON itself is pretty terrible, this is the best code model I could get to work with it, you will have to use the dynamic keyword to actually use the value data..... the way the top level 'value' is being used is not really cleanly parsable. As it stands it is an array that has 3 items, but two of them are strings and one of them is an object 'highlight'

```
public class Match
{
    public List<object> value { get; set; }
}

public class Snippets
{
    public List<Match> match { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Snippets snippets { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I realize it's not great, so hopefully we'll be able to change the response into something cleaner. I'll try implementing the dynamic suggestion if that's not possible.

Comment: the way value is defined as two different things is also a problem when creating the mapping classes. In one place its just a string and the other its an object.

Comment: The JSON is “pretty terrible” because it’s trying to represent mixed content, something JSON was not designed for. How would you rather see the JSON formatted to make it easier to bind to .NET objects? What about getting the results back as XML, which handles mixed content well? How do you plan to use the snippets downstream? As HTML, for example, in a search result screen? Would it make sense to transform them to HTML and just store a string (of HTML) in the .NET object?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you're sending is JavaScript compatible because in JS you can have different type of objects, string, numbers, etc. in an array.

But you declared the `values` array to be an `IEnumerable<string>`, that means `value` in the JSON you send **must** be an array of strings, you can't put an object because C# is has strongly typed arrays. What you're basically trying to do is this:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("123");
strings.Add(new { foo: "foo" });
```

That won't work.

The most simple solution is to change the JSON layout to be valid for C#.
You could use this:

```
"match": [{
    "value": {
        "text": "In (consolidated) enforcement actions for failure to answer subpoena, appeal from {0}  for defendants.",
        "markup": [{
            "type": "highlight",
            "value" : "judgement"
        }]

    }
}]
```

Add a class for `Markup`

```
public class Markup
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public string Value {get; set; }
}
```

Then another one for `Value`

```
public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "markup")]
    public IEnumerable<Markup> Markup {get; set; }
}
```

Then change `MarkLogicMatchModel`

```
public class MarkLogicMatchModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public IEnumerable<Value> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Later you could use `String.Format` to append the parsed markup to the text.
This will work if the input text does not have `{` or `}`, and if it comes from a component you control, of course.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to go use `dynamic` as Paul suggested, no other way. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788850/parse-json-string-to-a-json-object-in-c-sharp-without-writing-extra-object-class)

Comment: Thanks for the response--I'm talking to the other members of my team to see if we can change the JSON. If not I'll take a look at the dynamic way.

Answer (score 0):

Current .NET 6 ConfigurationBuilder offers an efficient Bind method in C#.

json file

```
{
  "Position": {
    "Title": "Editor",
    "Name": "Joe Smith",
    "Devs": [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ],
    "Param": {
      "Port": "1234"
    }
  }
}
```

call of Binding and config

```
_con = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("DeviceMapper.config.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
    .Build();

var positionOptions = new PositionOptions();
_con.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position).Bind(positionOptions);
Debug.WriteLine(positionOptions.Name);
```

models including nested class:

```
public class PositionOptions
{
    public class PositionParameter
    {
        public string Port { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Address { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    }

    public const string Position = "Position";

    public string Title { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    public List<string>? Devs { get; set; }

    public PositionParameter? Param { get; set; }
}
```

example project and code is on github
https://github.com/flowxcode/sharp-conf-binder